# How to pass a parameterised fixture as a parameter to another fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, parameterized-unit-test

I am trying to avoid repeating too much boilerplate in my tests, and I want to rewrite them in a more structured way. Let's say that I have two different parsers that both can parse a text into a `doc`. That doc would then be used in other tests. The end goal is to expose a `doc()` fixture that can be used in other tests, and that is parameterised in such a way that it runs all combinations of given parsers and texts.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def parser_a():
    return "parser_a"  # actually a parser object

@pytest.fixture
def parser_b():
    return "parser_b"  # actually a parser object

@pytest.fixture
def short_text():
    return "Lorem ipsum"

@pytest.fixture
def long_text():
    return "If I only knew how to bake cookies I could make everyone happy."
```

The question is, now, how to create a `doc()` fixture that would look like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture(params=???)
def doc(parser, text):
    return parser.parse(text)
```

where `parser` is parameterised to be parser_a and parser_b, and `text` to be short_text and long_text. This means that in total `doc` would test four combinations of parsers and text in total.

The documentation on PyTest's parameterised fixtures is quite vague and I could not find an answer on how to approach this. All help welcome.

Comment: The answer is that it isn't possible ATM, see [issue #349](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349). The [`pytest-lazy-fixture`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-lazy-fixture/) plugin claims having that functionality though, worth checking it out.

Comment: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but you could just use functions instead of fixtures, and combine these in fixtures:

```
import pytest

class Parser:  # dummy parser for testing
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def parse(self, text):
        return f'{self.name}({text})'


class ParserFactory:  # do not recreate existing parsers
    parsers = {}

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls, name):
        if name not in cls.parsers:
            cls.parsers[name] = Parser(name)
        return cls.parsers[name]

def parser_a():
    return ParserFactory.instance("parser_a") 

def parser_b():
    return ParserFactory.instance("parser_b")

def short_text():
    return "Lorem ipsum"

def long_text():
    return "If I only knew how to bake cookies I could make everyone happy."


@pytest.fixture(params=[long_text, short_text])
def text(request):
    yield request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=[parser_a, parser_b])
def parser(request):
    yield request.param

@pytest.fixture
def doc(parser, text):
    yield parser().parse(text())

def test_doc(doc):
    print(doc)
```

The resulting pytest output is:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
...
collecting ... collected 4 items

test_combine_fixt.py::test_doc[parser_a-long_text] PASSED                [ 25%]parser_a(If I only knew how to bake cookies I could make everyone happy.)

test_combine_fixt.py::test_doc[parser_a-short_text] PASSED               [ 50%]parser_a(Lorem ipsum)

test_combine_fixt.py::test_doc[parser_b-long_text] PASSED                [ 75%]parser_b(If I only knew how to bake cookies I could make everyone happy.)

test_combine_fixt.py::test_doc[parser_b-short_text] PASSED               [100%]parser_b(Lorem ipsum)


============================== 4 passed in 0.05s ==============================
```

*UPDATE:*
I added a singleton factory for the parser as discussed in the comments as an example.

*NOTE:*
I tried to use `pytest.lazy_fixture` as suggested by @hoefling. That works, and makes it possible to pass the parser and text directly from a fixture, but I couldn't get it (yet) to work in a way that each parser is instantiated only once. For reference, here is the changed code if using `pytest.lazy_fixture`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def parser_a():
    return Parser("parser_a")

@pytest.fixture
def parser_b():
    return Parser("parser_b")

@pytest.fixture
def short_text():
    return "Lorem ipsum"

@pytest.fixture
def long_text():
    return "If I only knew how to bake cookies I could make everyone happy."


@pytest.fixture(params=[pytest.lazy_fixture('long_text'),
                        pytest.lazy_fixture('short_text')])
def text(request):
    yield request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=[pytest.lazy_fixture('parser_a'),
                        pytest.lazy_fixture('parser_b')])
def parser(request):
    yield request.param


@pytest.fixture
def doc(parser, text):
    yield parser.parse(text)


def test_doc(doc):
    print(doc)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Won't that mean that the parsers will be created over and over again because they are not in fixtures?

Comment: True - if this is not wanted, this is not sufficient... I will have a look later.

Comment: I kind of circumvented the issue by having a global dict PARSERS and in your example, `def parser_a()` becomes something like: `if 'parser_a' not in PARSERS: PARSERS['parser_a'] = Parser('parser_a'); return PARSERS['parser_a']`. This seems to work but I am not sure if it has any caveats.

Comment: Yes, this is always a possibility - make them basically singletons. I didn't come up with another solution yet, and this will work at least. It may have side effects if the parser has a state that remains between tests - this has to be reset then. If it is stateless, there will be no problems.

Comment: I looked a bit further, and as @hoefling has pointed out in his comment, this seems not to be possible. So using a singleton together with combined fixtures is probably your best bet. Interesting question, anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Your fixture should look like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def doc_fixture(request):
    parser = request.param[0]
    text = request.param[1]
    return parser.parse(text)
```

and use it in following way:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('doc_fixture', [parser_1, 'short text'], indirect=True)
def test_sth(doc_fixture):
    ...  # Perform tests
```

You can mix and match combination of arguments using [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html)

Here is another example that provides different argument combinations:

```
from argparse import Namespace
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def doc_fixture(request):
    first_arg, second_arg = request.param
    s = Namespace()
    s.one = first_arg
    s.two = second_arg
    return s


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'doc_fixture',
    [
        ('parserA', 'ShortText'),
        ('parserA', 'LongText'),
        ('parserB', 'ShortText'),
        ('parserB', 'LongText')
    ],
    indirect=True
)
def test_something(doc_fixture):
    assert doc_fixture == ''
```

And an example run result (with failing tests as expected):

```
=========================================================================================== short test summary info ============================================================================================
FAILED ../../tmp/::test_something[doc_fixture0] - AssertionError: assert Namespace(one='parserA', two='ShortText') == ''
FAILED ../../tmp/::test_something[doc_fixture1] - AssertionError: assert Namespace(one='parserA', two='LongText') == ''
FAILED ../../tmp/::test_something[doc_fixture2] - AssertionError: assert Namespace(one='parserB', two='ShortText') == ''
FAILED ../../tmp/::test_something[doc_fixture3] - AssertionError: assert Namespace(one='parserB', two='LongText') == ''
```

Comment: Could you explain in words in your post how the `parameterize` line should be read (how the arguments relate).

Comment: Name of fixture, list of parameters, indirect=True specifies that params are sent to fixtrue.

Comment: I don't think this does what I want. If I understand correctly, you only send parser_a and short_text to the fixture, but I need to do it for all combinations of the parsers and the text.

Comment: @BramVanroy you can mix and match combinations of `pytest.mark.parametrize` edited the answer to add a more appropriate example.

Comment: @salparadise But now it just shows one level of fixtures, right? Aren't "'ShortText'" and "parserA" just strings? I need them to be fixtures themselves (or, as sown in MrBean's answer, by using singletons).

Comment: @BramVanroy, sure, I mean you can pass whatever types you want (parser objects if you may) however I understand your wish to pass in fixtures. Apologies I misunderstood that part of the requirement.

Comment: question is to pass parameter from a fixture to another fixture and not form a test method to a fixture